# iPhone app crash when used Facebook SDK's

Tags: facebook, web, view, sdk, integration

Could anyone help me to analyze the below crash log

I am trying to integrate Facebook on to the app, when I click a Facebook icon on the app, a Facebook login page is displayed as a web view with in the app. but the app crashes.

```
Thread 5 name:  Closure Thread
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x2bf9afaa WTFCrash + 54
1   WebCore                         0x36b218f8 WebCore::FloatingPointEnvironment::saveMainThreadEnvironment() + 28
2   WebCore                         0x36767882 StartWebThread() + 458
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39416d5c __pthread_once_handler + 48
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3940f864 _os_once + 40
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39414f16 pthread_once + 46
6   WebKitLegacy                    0x3727b34c +[WebView(WebPrivate) enableWebThread] + 272
7   WebKitLegacy                    0x3727a86a WebKitInitialize + 66
8   UIKit                           0x2e349fd6 ___UIApplicationLoadWebKit_block_invoke + 150
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x392ac2cc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x392acf0e dispatch_once_f + 58
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38d424d4 _class_initialize + 532
12  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38d4805a lookUpImpOrForward + 250
13  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38d47f52 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 30
14  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38d4e1d6 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 22
15  MYAPP                           0x000fc916 -[FBSDKWebDialogView initWithFrame:] (FBSDKWebDialogView.m:46)
16  MYAPP                           0x000eb1a4 -[FBSDKWebDialog show] (FBSDKWebDialog.m:90)
17  MYAPP                           0x000eafa6 +[FBSDKWebDialog showWithName:parameters:delegate:] (FBSDKWebDialog.m:52)
18  MYAPP                           0x006dbe06 -[FBSDKLoginManager(WebDialog) performWebLogInWithParameters:] (FBSDKLoginManager.m:634)
19  MYAPP                           0x006da52a -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithBehavior:] (FBSDKLoginManager.m:304)
20  MYAPP                           0x006da41c -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithPermissions:handler:] (FBSDKLoginManager.m:262)
21  MYAPP                           0x006d9576 -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:handler:] (FBSDKLoginManager.m:66)
22  MYAPP                           0x00073c78 +[ViewController facebookLoginClicked] (ViewController.m:44)
23  MYAPP                           0x000734a0 +[JSFacebookFFIAPI facebookLoginClicked:] (JSFacebookFFIAPI.m:43)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x2aa94660 __invoking___ + 64
25  CoreFoundation                  0x2a9bf488 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 296
26  MYAPP                           0x002005c8 -[Runtime executeStaticFunction:withArguments:exception:] (Runtime.m:1906)
27  MYAPP                           0x001ff11c staticDispatchFunction (Runtime.m:420)
28  MYAPP                           0x005c415e long long JSC::APICallbackFunction::call<JSC::JSCallbackFunction>(JSC::ExecState*) + 422
29  MYAPP                           0x00623dd4 JSC::LLInt::setUpCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Instruction*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*) + 396
30  MYAPP                           0x00622902 llint_slow_path_call + 118
31  MYAPP                           0x006285fc JSC::LLInt::CLoop::execute(JSC::ExecState*, void*, bool) + 16212
32  MYAPP                           0x00624228 callToJavaScript + 140
33  MYAPP                           0x005bb13e JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*, JSC::Register*) + 38
34  MYAPP                           0x005b99c2 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 534
35  MYAPP                           0x00591564 JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 44
36  MYAPP                           0x005f23e0 JSObjectCallAsFunction + 428
37  MYAPP                           0x001ffae0 -[Runtime executeJSFunction:thisObject:withArguments:] (Runtime.m:1773)
38  MYAPP                           0x00207406 -[JSFunctionExecuter execute:] (JSFunctionExecuter.m:55)
39  MYAPP                           0x00206f6c -[FunctionExecuter execute:] (FunctionExecuter.m:76)
40  MYAPP                           0x00150df0 doExecuteClosure (ClosureExecuter.m:43)
41  MYAPP                           0x001522d6 +[ClosureExecuter executeClosure:] (ClosureExecuter.m:262)
42  Foundation                      0x2b7ce5ca __NSThreadPerformPerform + 382
43  CoreFoundation                  0x2aa55fac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
44  CoreFoundation                  0x2aa553ba __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 214
45  CoreFoundation                  0x2aa53a20 __CFRunLoopRun + 768
46  CoreFoundation                  0x2a9a01fc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
47  CoreFoundation                  0x2a9a000e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
48  Foundation                      0x2b709138 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 260
49  MYAPP                           0x000ff454 -[VMThread main] (VMAppDelegate.m:271)
50  Foundation                      0x2b7ce3b6 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
51  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39415e20 _pthread_body + 136
52  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39415d92 _pthread_start + 114
53  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39413b1c thread_start + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Running on main thread resolved the issue